# What can you do with hadoop that is impossible or very hard to do with Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am rather new to Hadoop and Hive, and would like an example of something that could be easily done with Hadoop but for which hive is not a good fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is not a "relational workload" (e.g. stuff you could also do with a SQL database) is not very well-suited for Hive. There is probably always a way to do it also with Hive (primarily because UDFs are available) but it would not be "easily".

You're differentiating between "Hadoop" and "Hive". However, "Hadoop" is a rather general term: It could mean "HDFS" (the distributed file system), "YARN" (the resource manager) or "Hadoop" as an implementation of the "Map Reduce" algorithm suggested by Google. I assume you refer to "Map Reduce" when comparing Hadoop and Hive.

I would say computing a [page-rank with MapReduce](http://blog.xebia.com/2011/09/27/wiki-pagerank-with-hadoop/) is probably quite annoying with Hive. Another example would be computing [TF-IDF with MapReduce](https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-clusternet/wiki/RunningMapReduceExampleTFIDF).

Answer (score 1):

TF-IDF can be computed using Apache Hive with a Hivemall extension.
https://github.com/myui/hivemall/wiki/TFIDF-calculation

To compute TF-IDF, 2 views and 1 query are just required. Easy!